# Getting detected data from the UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using UITextView in my application.For textview i am using data detection as follow:

```
 UITextView *tv=[[UITextView alloc]init];
tv.dataDetectorTypes=UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;
```

Its fine . It is detecting the phone no. But I want to extract this phone no into another variable. Is there any provision to get detected data from UITextView ?