# How to get the detected text from the UITextView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting detected data from the UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648542/getting-detected-data-from-the-uitextview)

I have posted the same question yesterday but i haven't got the desired replies so i am posting this question again with the more clarification .sorry for this .
I am working with the UITextView . I made UITextView to detect all i.e. links ,address, events and phone no. Its fine it is giving me desired output as follow:
[image]

Now my requirement is to save  those phone no (123456) and email (abc@mail.com) into separate variable. Is there any provision or way to get the only detected text from the textview ?

Comment: If you posted the same question you should have edited it, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: so what ? I already stated that earlier .

Comment: If you don't get good answers, edit the question and make it better. Don't ask it twice. You should delete this question and edit the old one. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty

Comment: Just look at the views for my last question 29 in 24 hours .This question got 24 in 1 hours .And i got the perfect answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `NSDataDetector` (available iOS 4.0+, OS X 10.7+)
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html

You should be able to get the text out of the `UITextView` as an `NSString`, then run it through an `NSDataDetector`. You should be able to find more information on Stack Overflow and around the web by searching for `NSDataDetector`.